# Is there a way to group by approximate values in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to group values on an approximate basis in R, a "fuzzy grouping" if you will. Suppose you have the following values:

```
c( 1.0, 105.4, 1.5, 48.7, 1.2, 0.9, 50.0, 51.0, 100.0)
```

the grouping I am looking for would be:

```
c( 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.9)
c( 48.7, 50.0, 51.0)
c( 105.4 )
```

Is there a function that exists and can do this? If not, is there an efficient method to go about?

Comment: knn: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do 1d clustering. For example:

```
x <- c( 1.0, 105.4, 1.5, 48.7, 1.2, 0.9, 50.0, 51.0, 100.0)
kmeans(x, 3) #three groups
```

> ```
> K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 3, 4, 2
>
> Cluster means:
>     [,1]
> 1  49.90
> 2   1.15
> 3 102.70
>
> Clustering vector:
> [1] 2 3 2 1 2 2 1 1 3
>
> Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
> [1]  2.66  0.21 14.58
>  (between_SS / total_SS =  99.9 %)
>
> Available components:
>
> [1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"         "ifault"
> ```

```
split(x, kmeans(x, 3)$cluster)
```

> ```
> $`1`
> [1] 48.7 50.0 51.0
>
> $`2`
> [1] 105.4 100.0
>
> $`3`
> [1] 1.0 1.5 1.2 0.9
> ```